# SIMD code works in Debug, but does not in Release

Tags: rust, simd

This code works in debug mode, but panics because of the assert in release mode.

```
use std::arch::x86_64::*;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let a = vec![2.0f32, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];
        let b = -1.0f32;

        let ar = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.as_ptr());
        println!("ar: {:?}", ar);

        let br = _mm256_set1_ps(b);
        println!("br: {:?}", br);

        let mut abr = _mm256_setzero_ps();
        println!("abr: {:?}", abr);

        abr = _mm256_fmadd_ps(ar, br, abr);
        println!("abr: {:?}", abr);

        let mut ab = [0.0; 8];
        _mm256_storeu_ps(ab.as_mut_ptr(), abr);
        println!("ab: {:?}", ab);

        assert_eq!(ab[0], -2.0f32);
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a13b1ac0d287cba6230c2515f1ff87e0))

Comment: Could be related: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50154 or https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56950

Comment: I just filed the second actually. But yeah, good call.

Comment: Can confirm, I also get different (wrong) results for `_mm256_fmadd_ps` in release builds.

Comment: Looks like UB to me. You can't use vendor intrinsics unless the code is compiled with the corresponding CPU features.

Comment: I can confirm, if you enable the feature flag it will no longer panic...

Comment: @kali Did I answer your question? If so, please mark it as the answer. If not, what else would you like to know?

Comment: Yeah @BurntSushi5, I actually just needed the "you forgot the feature markers" nodge, so the hint on the github issue were enough. But thanks for the extensive anwser, it will certainly help someone else at some point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can indeed confirm that this code causes the assert to trip in release mode:

```
$ cargo run --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/release/so53831502`
ar: __m256(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
br: __m256(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
abr: __m256(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
abr: __m256(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ab: [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `-1.0`,
 right: `-2.0`', src/main.rs:24:9
```

This appears to be a compiler bug, see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50154) and [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D53554). In particular, you are calling routines like [`_mm256_set1_ps`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm256_set1_ps.html) and [`_mm256_fmadd_ps`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm256_fmadd_ps.html), which require the CPU features `avx` and `fma` respectively, but neither your code nor your compilation command indicate to the compiler that such features should be used.

One way of fixing this is to tell the compiler to compile the entire program with both the `avx` and `fma` features enabled, like so:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+avx,+fma" cargo run --release
   Compiling so53831502 v0.1.0 (/tmp/so53831502)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.36s
     Running `target/release/so53831502`
ar: __m256(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
br: __m256(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
abr: __m256(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
abr: __m256(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ab: [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Another approach that achieves the same result is to tell the compiler to use all available CPU features on your CPU:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo run --release
   Compiling so53831502 v0.1.0 (/tmp/so53831502)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.34s
     Running `target/release/so53831502`
ar: __m256(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
br: __m256(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
abr: __m256(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
abr: __m256(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ab: [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

However, both of these compilation commands produce binaries that can only run on CPUs that support the `avx` and `fma` features. If that's not a problem for you, then this is a fine solution. If you would instead like to build portable binaries, then you can perform CPU feature detection at runtime, and compile certain functions with specific CPU features enabled. It is then your responsibility to guarantee that said functions are only invoked when the corresponding CPU feature is enabled and available. This process is documented as part of the [dynamic CPU feature detection](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/arch/index.html#dynamic-cpu-feature-detection) section of the `std::arch` docs.

Here's an example that uses runtime CPU feature detection:

```
use std::arch::x86_64::*;
use std::process;

fn main() {
    if is_x86_feature_detected!("avx") && is_x86_feature_detected!("fma") {
        // SAFETY: This is safe because we're guaranteed to support the
        // necessary CPU features.
        unsafe { doit(); }
    } else {
        eprintln!("unsupported CPU");
        process::exit(1);
    }
}

#[target_feature(enable = "avx,fma")]
unsafe fn doit() {
    let a = vec![2.0f32, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];
    let b = -1.0f32;

    let ar = _mm256_loadu_ps(a.as_ptr());
    println!("ar: {:?}", ar);

    let br = _mm256_set1_ps(b);
    println!("br: {:?}", br);

    let mut abr = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    println!("abr: {:?}", abr);

    abr = _mm256_fmadd_ps(ar, br, abr);
    println!("abr: {:?}", abr);

    let mut ab = [0.0; 8];
    _mm256_storeu_ps(ab.as_mut_ptr(), abr);
    println!("ab: {:?}", ab);

    assert_eq!(ab[0], -2.0f32);
}
```

To run it, you no longer need to set any compilation flags:

```
$ cargo run --release
   Compiling so53831502 v0.1.0 (/tmp/so53831502)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.29s
     Running `target/release/so53831502`
ar: __m256(2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
br: __m256(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
abr: __m256(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
abr: __m256(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
ab: [-2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

If you run the resulting binary on a CPU that doesn't support either `avx` or `fma`, then the program should exit with an error message: `unsupported CPU`.

In general, I think the docs for `std::arch` could be improved. In particular, the key boundary at which you need to split your code is dependent upon whether your vector types appear in your function signature. That is, the `doit` routine does not require anything beyond the standard x86 (or x86_64) function ABI to call, and is thus safe to call from functions that don't otherwise support `avx` or `fma`. However, internally, the function has been told to compile its code using additional instruction set extensions based on the given CPU features. This is achieved via the `target_feature` attribute. If you, for example, supplied an incorrect target feature:

```
#[target_feature(enable = "ssse3")]
unsafe fn doit() {
    // ...
}
```

then the program exhibits the same behavior as your initial program.

Comment: *your code exhibits undefined behavior, and thus, the result is **technically legal*** — did you mean... illegal?

Comment: @Shepmaster pretty much legal. In the face of UB, the Rust program could even purchase bed sheets from IKEA and eat them.

Comment: @Shepmaster Hah, yeah, E_net4 has it right. Since its UB, any result is technically "legal."

Comment: For all watching: I spoke to Alex Crichton, and he believes this isn't UB, but is actually a compiler bug. See edit in answer above. Note though that the rest of my answer still applies---if you're using vendor intrinsics, then you need to tell the compiler to build your code using those features. You could otherwise be subject to performance bugs or runtime errors like SIGILL.